# How to remove iOS 14 widget from Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, widgetkit

I have an Xcode project with an iOS 14 widget.

I would like to completely (and safely) remove the widget from the project.

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension), as far as I can tell, does not give instructions on how to accomplish this task.

When you *add* the widget extension, Xcode does a bunch of stuff for you automatically. This makes me think that there's more to the story than simply deleting the widget folder/code.

**Question:** What steps do I need to complete to safely remove the widget extension from my project?

Thank you!